# YAML - DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 to download files with specific extension

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a YAML file with a task to download the artifact:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    artifact: '$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(BuildConfiguration)'
    path: Service\ProjectName
```

Logs for this task:

```
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Hosts.Console/Hosts.Console.csproj
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Hosts.Console/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Hosts.Console.dll
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Hosts.Console/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Entities.dll
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Hosts.Console/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Hosts.Console.deps.json
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Hosts.Console/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Entities.pdb
Downloading: D:\a\1\s\Service\ProjectName\Hosts.Console/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Hosts.Console.exe
```

I only want to download files that end with **.csproj**

How do I update the task to perform that?

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    artifact: '$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(BuildConfiguration)'
    #patterns:
    path: Service\ProjectName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `patterns` [argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#arguments) in the task.

`patterns`:(Optional) One or more file matching patterns (new line delimited) that limit which files get downloaded. [More Information on file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops). Argument aliases: `itemPattern`

For example: Given the pattern `**/*.csproj`.